# I can not link Note to a contact

Tags: rest-api, contact, relationships, salesforce-id

I am writing a very simple plugin which creates Contact and associate a note to it. 
I noticed that to add a note to a contact, I should first create the contact after that add the note here is my simple code divided it into two steps:

1- Create the new Contact Record

```
        Contact NewContactRecord = new Contact();
                NewContactRecord.FirstName = Result.name;
                NewContactRecord.Email = Result.email;
                NewContactRecord.Phone = Result.phone;
                NewContactRecord.Title = Result.job;
SaveResult[] CreatedContact = _SForceRef.create(new sObject[] { NewContactRecord });
```

2- Associate the Contact with the note

```
 if (CreatedContact[0].id!=null)
  {
                    Note Notes = new Note();
                    Notes.Title = "Note Title";// Result.notes;
                    Notes.Body = "Note Body"; //Result.notes;
                    Notes.ParentId = CreatedContact[0].id;
                    Notes.IsPrivate = false;
                    SaveResult[] CreatedNote = _SForceRef.create(new sObject[] { Notes });
                    if (CreatedNote[0].success)
                        textBox1.Text = string.Format("Is The note created={0}" , CreatedNote[0].success);
                    else
                        textBox1.Text = CreatedNote[0].errors[0].message;
    }
```

It always gives me that the note is created but I didn`t see it neighter linked with the contact nor at Notes Entity

Comment: please take the time to format your post next time =) . and welcome to SFSE!

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to be correct; I tested similar code in my developer org. I think your issue has to do with object access and display.

Salesforce has two systems for attaching Files and Notes to records.

The newer system uses a group of objects whose names start with `Content`, such as `ContentDocument` (an attached file) and `ContentNote`, an attached note.

The older system uses the `Note` and `Attachment` objects, as you're using here.

Depending on the configuration of your Salesforce org and specifically its related lists, you may not see older-style `Note` and `Attachment` records at all. Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

`Note` records appear only in the "Notes & Attachments" related list (which shows `Note` and `Attachment` sObjects), but *not* in the "Notes" related list (which shows `ContentNote` sObjects). Similarly, the "Files" related list shows `ContentDocument` sObjects, and `Attachment` records show only in "Notes & Attachments".

It's recommended that newer code always use the Content objects, as this is the direction of development for Salesforce.